# php doesn't write in text file on localhost?

Tags: php

i have this text file on my localhost, trying to write into it via PHP but it wont allow me for HTTP wrapper issue, but it does work if .txt file is on hard drive.

thanks

Comment: Post your example code, please.

Comment: maybe you need a chmod

Comment: check if apache has write permissions on that file

Comment: You are most probably having issues with write privileges in the directory you are writing to. If its a windows machine, i don't think this should occur. But if you're on a Mac or any other unix based system, then you need to look into a command called `chmod` and use it to set the write privileges for the directory you are trying to write to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to `fopen('http://...', 'w')` then yes, that won't work. It doesn't matter that the file may be on the same physical server, the server itself doesn't know that. A `http://...` URL can lead anywhere, and of course you cannot simply write to any arbitrary file on any arbitrary server via HTTP. I hope it's obvious that you cannot `fopen('http://google.com/somefile.txt', 'w')`, so why do you expect to be able to do the same with your own domain?

Use a local file path:

```
fopen('/path/to/my/file.txt', 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

specify file location to write

```
<?php
    $myFile = "testFile.txt";
    $fh = fopen(C:\\test\\text.txt, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    $stringData = "Tracy Tanner\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
```